# Why Visual Studio 2015 changes web.config after web deploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, web-deployment

When I do local publishing in Visual Studio 2015. It publishes web.config which contains:

```
  <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd"/>
```

and the website works. But when i do web deploy, it publishes web.config which contains:

```
 <httpPlatform processPath="%home%\site\approot\web.cmd" />
```

, website could not find web.cmd and doesnt work. How can i publish the project with string "..\approot\web.cmd" without %home% in web.config over web deploy?

Comment: How are you exactly building the project ? In release mode ?

Comment: Can you desqribe your question with more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some helpful information you can fid [here](http://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-core-hosting-azure-app-service/)

> When Visual Studio deploys an ASP.NET Core app to Azure App Service,
>   it sets an environment variable called DNU_PUBLISH_AZURE to 1 before
>   calling dnu publish. This tells dnu publish to fill in the correct
>   values, which are:

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%home%\site\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
```

Seting values 0 or false to variable DNU_PUBLISH_AZURE turns back normal path.

Azure environment turns on in pubxml in publish profiles in string:

```
<_DestinationType>AzureWebSite</_DestinationType>
```

In my case i should to remove this string.